# onclick div value change

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change the div values by clicking the option value. I tried some way to achieve it. It works fine in Firefox. But chrome it is not working. This my fiddle address. I couldn't find the solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/gzcz5/2/

This is my script code:

```
$(".citydrop option").click(function(){
    var count=$(".citydrop option").length;
    var idval=$(this).attr('value');
    $(".neighborhoods ul.lists").each(function() { 
        $(this).css("display","none");
    });
    $('ul#'+idval).css("display","block");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$(".citydrop").change(function(){` instead `$(".citydrop option").click(function(){` and remove `attr('value');` and paste the `val()`

Try this,

```
$(".citydrop").change(function(){
    var count=$(".citydrop option").length;
    var idval=$(this).val();
    $(".neighborhoods ul.lists").each(function(){
        $(this).css("display","none");
    });
    $('ul#'+idval).css("display","block");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gzcz5/3/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will implement it and let you know.